# Biztalk flat file validatation without transform it into XML format

Tags: biztalk

I have a Biztalk 2006R2, which receives some flat files from publisher systems and then transfer these flat files to subscriber systems.

I would like to add the validation on these flat files, without transform it in to XML formatted files.

How should I proceed on it?

I have tried using "Flat File disassember", it can validate the flat file, but at the same time, it will transform the flat file into XML formatted files for further routing, which is NOT our target.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: The single solution I see here - custom pipeline component with message body stream (string) validation.

Comment: BTW, why do you trying to avoid xml?

Comment: Any sample code for buidling custom pipeline component with message body validation? thx

Answer (score 2):

To answer you specific question, no.  BizTalk cannot natively validate any message without converting to Xml or it being Xml originally.

In your situation though, this still shouldn't be a problem since the schema you use to disassembler to Xml and validate should also be able to re-serialize the Xml to ff.

So:

1. Receive the flat file and allow the Flat File Disassembler to parse and validate.
2. Route the Xml to a Send Port with a Flat File Assembler to convert the message back to the original format.

Technically, there are ways to actually preserve the original:

1. Write a custom Disassembler component that wraps the Flat File Disassembler and keeps a copy of the original stream.
2. Execute the Pipeline in an Orchestration.

Comment: If using flat file disassembler in receivelocation to disassemble the flat file to xml file and then flat file assembler in sendport to assemble back to flat file, any chance the flat file is not the same as the original one? thanks.

Comment: Any chance?  Sure, but it depends on the developer :)  However, that would rarely be my concern so long as the file can be interpreted the same, business wise, which is what should matter.